# VARCHARS: 2, 4, 8, 16, etc.? Or 1, 3, 7, 15, etc.?

Tags: sql, mysql, storage, limit, varchar

I see VARCHAR(255) being used all the time instead of VARCHAR(256), but I also see VARCHAR(16) being used instead of VARCHAR(15). This seems inconsistent to me. If an extra byte is being used to store the VARCHAR's length, shouldn't this rule also apply to the smaller lengths like 2, 4, 8 to be 1, 3, 7, instead?

Or am I totally missing something?

In other words, if I have a number that I know will never be above 12, should I just go ahead and use a VARCHAR(15) or VARCHAR(16) instead? Because it uses the same amount of space as a VARCHAR(12)? If so, which one do I use? 15 or 16? Does this rule change at all when I get closer to 256?

I use both MySQL and SQL, depending on the project.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> In other words, if I have a number that I know will never be above 12, should I just go ahead and use a VARCHAR(15) or VARCHAR(16) instead?

No!  Use varchar(12) (or maybe even char(12) if the length is fairly constant ).

Once upon a time the varchar type was limited to 255 characters on some systems ([including MySql prior to 5.0.3](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,37000,37052)) because the first byte stored indicated the length of the field.  Given this restriction, devs wanting to allow a reasonable amount of text would choose 255 rather than going to a different data type altogether.

But if you know the size of your data, definitely use exactly that size for the database.

Comment: Thanks. Everybody's answers were helpful, but I had to choose one.

Comment: **@geocar:** If your database locale is configured correctly, `VARCHAR(12)` will hold 12 characters. **`VARCHAR` is locale-aware**

Answer (score 4):

It has nothing to do with odd or even numbers.

Historically, 255 characters has often been the maximum length of a `VARCHAR` in various DBMSes. The length limit for a field that wasn't an `LOB` (Large Object) back then was 255 bytes (1 byte int). So the first byte was used to store the length of the field (0-255), and the remaining `n` bytes for the characters. That's why you often see `VARCHAR(255)`.

If the field will never be greater than 12, use `VARCHAR(12)`.

Comment: The reason it's 255 is because when you use the first byte to store the length of the field, that 8 bit byte can only indicate lengths from 0 to 255.

Comment: **@Joel:** True, just didn't want to go into the semantics. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think the original issue is that for some systems VARCHAR(...) was limited to 255, because when you use one byte to encode the actual length, you can only express lengths upto 255.

VARCHAR(16) / VARCHAR(15) it's most likely reminiscent of these origins, but there is nothing special in the two values.

Comment: I think a lot of the reason you see 15 and 16 is because programmers thought they were "optimizing" but just ended up confusing future programmers as to what their intentions were.

Comment: LOL that's exactly what I was thinking! And it worked! It rendered me completely confused about the matter. Thanks!